# laravel join on query not working and gives ambiguous error

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to append a `join` to my query builder and I get this error:

> message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `accommodation_rooms` inner join `room_pricing_histories` on `accommodation_rooms`.`id` = `room_pricing_histories`.`accommodation_room_id` and `room_pricing_histories`.`from_date` = 2019-10-05 15:49:21 where `id` in (1, 2) order by `room_pricing_histories`.`sales_price` desc limit 1)",
>   code: "23000",
>   status_code: 500,

This is my code here

```php
public function cheapestRoom()
{
    $roomIds = $this->accommodationRooms()->pluck('id')->toArray();
    return AccommodationRoom::whereIn('id', $roomIds)
        ->join('room_pricing_histories', function ($join) {
            $join->on('accommodation_rooms.id', '=', 'room_pricing_histories.accommodation_room_id')
                ->where('room_pricing_histories.from_date', Carbon::now());
        })
        ->orderBy('room_pricing_histories.sales_price', 'DESC')
        ->first();
}
public function getCheapestRoomAttribute()
{
    return $this->cheapestRoom();
}
protected $appends = ['cheapest_room'];
```

what I am trying to do is to get the cheapest room and append that to hotel model

Comment: You need to define **id** in `where id in(1,2)` part from which table it's taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `whereIn` query clause to specify which table to query from

Either

```php
return AccommodationRoom::whereIn('accommodation_rooms.id', $roomIds)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks the error is gone but it does not brining any result any idea how and why ?? because i think some thing is wrong with the join i guess

Comment: That's a different question for a different post, we don't do this here

Comment: your right sorry i try to figure out what is the problem ty :)